# Force a theme to @android:drawables supporting low level APIs

Tags: android, android-drawable

is there a way to force a button using system resources such as `@android:drawable/ic_menu_send` be with the background I choose?

the default is this:

[image: ic_menu_send light]

and the desired one for me is this: 
 [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try [style attributes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html) starting with "?":
`?android:drawable/ic_menu_send`

**Update:**

As it seems it is not that easy. First you have to check for which `drawables` there is an entry in the SDK resources, e.g. look in folder `android-sdk/platforms/android-15/data/res` of your Android SDK installation. There you can `grep` for your `drawable`.

In the following example we find that there is no entry for `ic_menu_send` in `themes.xml` (only in `public.xml`) and therefore no entry for the corresponding attribute in `attrs.xml`.

A drawable which would work is `ic_menu_share` where we can find entries in `themes.xml`and `attrs.xml` so we can use the style attribute in the following way `android:src="?android:actionModeShareDrawable"`

```
jh@jh-aspire:/opt/android-sdk/platforms/android-15/data/res$ grep -r ic_menu_send *
values/public.xml:  <public type="drawable" name="ic_menu_send" id="0x01080050" />

jh@jh-aspire:/opt/android-sdk/platforms/android-15/data/res$ grep -r ic_menu_share *
values/public.xml:  <public type="drawable" name="ic_menu_share" id="0x01080052" />
values/themes.xml:        <item name="actionModeShareDrawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_share_holo_dark</item>
values/themes.xml:        <item name="actionModeShareDrawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_share_holo_light</item>
values/themes.xml:        <item name="actionModeShareDrawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_share_holo_dark</item>
values/themes.xml:        <item name="actionModeShareDrawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_share_holo_light</item>
values/themes.xml:        <item name="actionModeShareDrawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_share_holo_dark</item>

jh@jh-aspire:/opt/android-sdk/platforms/android-15/data/res$ grep -r actionModeShareDrawable *
menu/webview_copy.xml:        android:icon="?android:attr/actionModeShareDrawable"
values/attrs.xml:        <attr name="actionModeShareDrawable" format="reference" />
values/themes.xml:        <item name="actionModeShareDrawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_share_holo_dark</item>
values/themes.xml:        <item name="actionModeShareDrawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_share_holo_light</item>
values/themes.xml:        <item name="actionModeShareDrawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_share_holo_dark</item>
values/themes.xml:        <item name="actionModeShareDrawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_share_holo_light</item>
values/themes.xml:        <item name="actionModeShareDrawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_share_holo_dark</item>
```

Comment: Could you explain how to apply the correct "style attribute" to get the desired image?

Comment: Actually I cannot explain it better than the above link. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Well, if I put it in an ImageButton "android:src" attribute, for example, `?android:drawable/ic_menu_send` doesn't exist, and `@android:drawable/ic_menu_send` returns the original white variation.

Comment: @Etan: you are right, this example doesn't work. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to use the desired icon from the "Action Bar Icon Pack" provided by Google
referenced on http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html#action-bar

There you will find the icon `6_social_send_now.png` for `holo_light` and `holo_dark` theme.

One reason to not reference system icons directly from the SDK is given in ["The Busy Coder's Guide to Android"](http://commonsware.com/Android/) by Mark L. Murphy: "However, there is a risk: device manufacturers are welcome to replace these drawables with their own artwork." and those might not fit to the other (selfmade) icons in your app.